# Program is not searching entire file

Tags: c, file, search

I am writing a program in which I need to search for several full-written numbers. The searching part seems to work but for some reason the program is skipping several words.
My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
    char temp[128];
    char *words[] = {"een","twee","drie","vier","vijf","zes","zeven","acht",
"negen","tien","elf","twaalf","dertien","veertien",
"vijftien","zestien","zeventien","achttien",
"negentien","twintig"};

    //Open the file
    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen("numbers.txt","r");
    int count = sizeof(myFile);
    if (myFile == NULL){
        printf("File not found\n");
    }
    else {
        //Search the words
        while(!feof(myFile)){
            //Get the words
            fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), myFile);
                for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i){

                    if((strstr(temp, words[i])) != NULL) {
                    printf("%s\n", temp);
                    }

                }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The mentioned file "numbers.txt" is as follows:

```
een
foo
drie
twee
acht
bla
zes
twaalf
elf
vier
```

The programs output:

```
een
drie
twee
acht
zes
vier
```

This means it is skipping "twaalf" and "elf". Why is it and how can I fix this?

Thanks on forehand.

Comment: This statement `int count = sizeof(myFile)` does not set `count` to size of myFile. It setts `count` to size of pointer to `FILE` struct, which in general is 4 on 32-bit systems and 8 on 64-bit systems. So in statement `for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)` you are iterating over first 8 elements of your array. You should set count to `sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0])`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int count = sizeof(myFile);
```

That seems to be a typo or a misunderstanding. `sizeof(myFile)` evaluates to the number of bytes used by a pointer. You need to use:

```
int count = sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0]);
```

The value of `count` will be the number of words after that.

Comment: But why is he getting the numbers 1 to 8 in the names of his language? He must have 8 byte pointers then, hence using x64?

Comment: @TobiasKnauss, that is corfrect.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `count` and `i` wrong.
The file has 10 lines, you set `count` to this number 10, and use it then to access your number array also. You need to set `count` to the number of elements in your array instead.

Comment: _"you set count to this number 10"_  :
  
No, sizeof gives variable size, not the number of lines or bytes in a file or whatever else.

Comment: Okay, but `sizeof(myfile)` is the wrong part. You don't need the size of the file, but the number of elements in your array! I thought you'd get that.

Comment: Of course, but you wrote " you set `count` to this number 10" which is obviously wrong, what means you do not understand how `sizeof` works.

Comment: No, I didn't know in this moment, because I have been using c# in the last years, where I didn't need sizeof. I had to go far back in my mind to remember of pure c++.